# How to append an output that is looping rather than making each loop its own line

Tags: python, loops, append

I read a few similar questions, but none helped in my situation. I have a loop that goes through a csv file and extracts IPs. I would then like to string these IPs as you see in the code below where 'adding='. How do I get the stringed IPs to append each time they are added rather than make a new line every time?

Code tried:

```
for i in x['Agent IP']:
    data = (i) 
    adding = {'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': str(data)}
    print(adding)
```

Output received:

```
{'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': '192.168.0.1'}
{'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': '192.168.0.2'}
{'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': '192.168.0.3'}
{'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': '192.168.0.4'}
```

I would like the output to append each one with a common in between them like so:

```
{'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': '192.168.0.1'}, {'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': '192.168.0.2'}, {'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': '192.168.0.3'}, {'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': '192.168.0.4'}
```

Comment: You tagged your question with `append`; why didn't you try and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a list:

```
res = []

for i in x['Agent IP']:
    data = (i) 
    adding = {'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': str(data)}
    res.append(adding)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of printing it out you can make a list and append it so at the beginning of your code you can call `information = list()` and right where your print function is you can call `information.append(adding)` and at the end of the file you can call `print(information)`